# Why is my read query to Firebase Realtime Database so slow?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have a database in a Firebase Realtime Database with data that looks like this:

```
root
|_history
  |_{userId}
    |_{n1}
    | |_ ...
    |_{n2}
    |_{n...}
```

Nodes `n` are keyed with a date integer value. Each `n` node has at least 60 keys, with some values being arrays, max 5 levels deep.

Query times were measured in a fashion similar to this:

```js
const startTime = performance.now();

await query();

const endTime = performance.now();

logger.info(`Query completed in ${endTime - startTime} ms`);
```

I have a function that queries for `n` nodes under `history/${userId}` with keys between and inclusive of the start and end values:

```js
await admin
  .database()
  .ref(`history/${userId}`)
  .orderByKey()
  .startAt(`${start}`)
  .endAt(`${end}`)
  .once("value")
```

This query is executed in a callable cloud function. This query currently takes approximately 2-3 seconds, returning approximately 225 nodes. The total number of `n` nodes is currently less than 300. Looking through my logs, it looks like query times that returned 0 nodes took approximately 500 milliseconds.

Why are the queries so slow? Am I misunderstanding something about Firebase's Realtime Database?

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, so just a few troubleshooting questions/comments: 1) The index seems irrelevant to the query you run, 2) How much data are you retrieving? Where do you run this code? What is the bandwidth there?  3) How is the performance impacted when you retrieve less data, either by reducing the range between `start` and `end`, or by reducing the amount of data per node?

Comment: I've updated the question body with more information that should at least partially cover the questions in your comment. Let me know if the added information is sufficient or if you still need more details.

Comment: Since you say you run this in Cloud Functions, can you test with a local Node.js script to see if the performance is the same? If not, then the code in your question is probably irrelevant to the performance.

Comment: Quick test bed with the JS SDK for comparison: https://jsbin.com/lefosid/6/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks for your effort on this! I restructured some of the data. This has resolved the issue with the first query in my last edit, I've got it down to under 10 ms. I have updated the question, removing info around that first query.

Comment: I suspect the second query takes so long because the nodes are large – each has ~60 keys, up to 5 levels deep and some values are arrays, total character length >4000. Would you agree with this suspicion? If it is correct, I did not expect the impact to be so large since the query is just on the node's key. The data itself comes from a third party API and the request time is <200 ms. In this case I might as well not store the data on Firebase Realtime database and just store IDs and hit the network to the third party API every time I need to request the data.

Comment: From a local test script, a retrieval of just one node takes ~1100 ms. Retrieval of zero nodes takes ~800 ms.

Comment: "I suspect the second query takes so long because the nodes are large " That was the reasons I asked for the amount of data in my first comment ;-)
It has nothing to do with the query itself, and is all about bandwidth. To make it faster, retrieve less data (as shown in my test results below).

Comment: Please don't remove parts of the question that I might have addressed below btw. We're trying to build a knowledge base here, and if you remove the problem - that leaves my answer on that part lingering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237974/discussion-between-wing-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Answer (score 1):

I've run a few performance tests to allow you to compare against.

I populated my database with this script:

```
for (var i=0; i < 500; i++) {
  ref.push({
    refresh_at: Date.now() + Math.round(Math.random() * 60 * 1000)
  });
}
```

This lead to a JSON of this form:

```
{
  "-MlWgH51ia7Iz7ubZb7K" : {
    "refresh_at" : 1633726623247
  },
  "-MlWgH534FgMlb7J4bH2" : {
    "refresh_at" : 1633726586126
  },
  "-MlWgH54gd-uW_M7e6J-" : {
    "refresh_at" : 1633726597651
  },
  ...
}
```

When retrieved in its entirety through the API, the `snapshot.val()` for this JSON is 26.001 characters long.

---

#### Client-side JavaScript SDK in jsbin

With the regular client-side JavaScript SDK in a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/lefosid/edit?js,console) and with a simple node script similar to yours.

Updated for jsbin, the code I ran is:

```
ref.orderByChild("refresh_at")
  .endAt(Date.now())
  .limitToLast(1000) //  This is what we'll vary
  .once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
  var endTime = performance.now();
  console.log('Query completed in '+Math.round(endTime - startTime)+'ms, retrieved '+snapshot.numChildren()+" nodes, for a total JSON size of "+JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()).length+" chars");  
});
```

Running it a few times, and changing the `limit` that I marked, leads to:

| Limit | Snapshot size | Average time in ms |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 26,001 | 350ms - 420ms |
| 100 | 5,201 | 300ms - 350ms |
| 10 | 521 | 300ms - 320ms |

---

#### Node.js Admin SDK

I ran the same test with a local Node.js script against the exact same data set, with a modified script that runs 10 times:

```
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  const startTime = Date.now();
  const snapshot = await ref.orderByChild("refresh_at")
    .endAt(Date.now())
    .limitToLast(10)
    .once("value")
  const endTime = Date.now();
  console.log('Query completed in '+Math.round(endTime - startTime)+'ms, retrieved '+snapshot.numChildren()+" nodes, for a total JSON size of "+JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()).length+" chars");  
};
```

The results:

| Limit | Snapshot size | Time in ms |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 26,001 | 507ms, 78ms, 70ms, 65ms, 65ms, 61ms, 64ms, 65ms, 81ms, 62ms |
| 100 | 5,201 | 442ms, 59ms, 56ms, 59ms, 55ms, 54ms, 54ms, 55ms, 57ms, 56ms |
| 10 | 521 | 437ms, 52ms, 49ms, 52ms, 51ms, 51ms, 52ms, 50ms, 52ms, 50ms |

So what you can see is that the first run is similar (but slightly slower) as the JavaScript SDK, and subsequent runs are then a lot faster. This makes sense as on the initial run the client establishes its (web socket) connection to the database server, which includes a few roundtrips to determine the right server. Subsequent calls seem more bandwidth constrained.

---

#### Ordering by key

I also test with `ref.orderByKey().startAt("-MlWgH5QUkP5pbQIkVm0").endAt("-MlWgH5Rv5ij42Vel5Sm")` in Node.js and get very similar results to the ordering by child.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `field` that you are using for the query to the Realtime Database rules.

For example

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null",
    "v1": {
            "history": {
                ".indexOn": "refresh_at"
            }   
        }
    }
}
```